# Python image classification in tensorflow .12 removed?

Tags: tensorflow

There used to be a classify_image.py in 0.11, now the only image classification I see if for C++ in `/examples/label_image`.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=classify_image.py

Is the file renamed and moved? How can I classify an image in python with TF .12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, note that now the models directory is a whole new repository in Tensorflow's organization.

The file you want has been moved to: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/imagenet

> Simple image classification with Inception. Run image classification
>   with Inception trained on ImageNet 2012 Challenge data set.